# SSIS Script Editor throws an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, bids, vsta

I have SQL Server 2012, SSIS, SSDT and Visual Studio 2010.  I can create a new SSIS package and add a Script Task, but if I attempt to open the Script Editor for that Script Task I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Cannot show Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Applications editor.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Core, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (mscorlib)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

From my own investigation into this error, I found that Visual Studio Tools for Applications appears to be a part of MS Office 2007 and higher.  This seemed like an odd dependency for to have, but I installed MS Office 2010 just for grins.  It didn't change anything.  What else should I try?

Comment: I've seen this before in earlier versions. If I remember correctly, I reinstalled .Net to correct it. I haven't experienced it in 2012, yet. You may want to consult http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/564956/cannot-show-visual-studio-2008-tools-for-applications-editor and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/e5337b0c-7f70-4603-859e-fbc7d0cf1c37 - I cannot remember what worked the last time I encountered this message in SSIS 2008... Apologies I cannot be more help.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I uninstalled and reinstalled SQL Server 2012 as recommended by the links you provided.  The installation completed without any errors but now nothing SSIS related works.  I get a half dozen errors saying "[such and such] is not installed correctly" when I attempt to open my SSIS package project in Visual Studio.  What a nightmarish web of dependencies this thing is!

Comment: Hi Ray, I am sorry to hear about this experience. A couple questions: 1) Are you installing the RTM version of SQL Server 2012? 2) Is this a "clean" installation (are you installing over a release candidate or other pre-release software)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out my problem this morning. When I uninstalled SQL Server 2012 (and the remnants of 2008 left behind when I upgraded last month) I also uninstalled 3 packages that were actually part of Visual Studio 2010.  Had I not done this, a reinstallation of SQL Server 2012 would probably have done the trick, but instead I found new errors.  When I reinstalled these 3 packages from the Visual Studio 2010 distribution media, everything started working.

The 3 packages in question were:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-tier Application Project
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-tier Application Framework
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service

Answer (score 6):

You will also get this error, if you are trying to debug a script task in VS 2010 and Run64BitRuntime is set to true. In order to debug, set it to false.

Comment: This worked for me. For those who don't know how to find that variable, follow this: Right Click on your *PROJECTNAME* under `Solution Explorer` then `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `Debugging` -> `Debug Options` -> `Run64BitRuntime` -> Should be `True`, set it to `False`.  Also helps: http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20run%20SSIS%20Packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm

Comment: Changing the runtime fixed it for me. Thank you, sirs!

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error and nothing I came across corrected the problem until I logged off as my normal user and logged in as my local admin user. Once I logged in as an admin I could edit the script in my package. Once I logged back in as my regular user the edit script button worked for it too.

I assume it needed to register the assembly on the first launch and couldn't with my regular domain user.

Comment: Running VS 2010 as an admin worked for me as well. Then after it loaded fine for the 1st time it worked in non-admin mode from then on

Answer (score 1):

I also got this same error when trying to open the Script Editor, but for a different reason.  Not sure how it happened, but I had 3 copies of VSTA (different versions) installed.  Once I removed all of them and re-installed SQL Server 2012, problem solved.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was:

- close bids (I'm on 2008r2)
- reopen
- edit the script (it allowed me to edit it once after restarting bids)
- delete all breakpoints
- make a trivial change, such as adding a blank line
- save

That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me without doing any kind uninstall.**

My environment:
Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 (2008)

Solution:

1. Go to cd "C:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\common7\ide\"
2. Execute command vsta.exe /setup /hostid SSIS_ScriptTask. This will open VSTA with blank project. Let it open and then close it.
3. Execute command vsta.exe /setup /hostid SSIS_ScriptComponent. This will open VSTA with blank project. Let it open and then close it.
4. Open your solution/packages that contains the script task.
5. Click Edit button in Script task and it should open now. Just in case if it dont, I would suggest to keep the blank vsta of step 2 & 3 open and then click the Edit button in script task.

Took almost two hours and thankfully it worked for me. I did not have admin right to perform all that nasty uninstall and registry edit solutions.

Hope it helps someone!!!

Reference : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jason_howell/archive/2010/08/18/vsta-setup-and-configuration-troubles-for-ssis-2008-and-r2-installations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Cannot show Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Applications editor.**

Just follow the below solution:

1. Go to SQL Server Setup folder.
2. Inside that folder "redist".
3. Under that one more folder "VSTA".
4. Under VSTA folder "X86" and "X64"
5. Install the VSTA_RT30.
6. It works fine.