# cannot show Visual Studio Tools for Application editor in SSIS 2012

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, vsta

When I click on EDIT SCRIPT button for Script Task in SSIS 2012 package,

It does not open the Script editor rather it shows:

> "cannot show Visual Studio Tools for Application editor"
>
> Couls not load file or assembly
>   "Microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.core version=10.0.0.0 ...."
>   system can not find the file assembly specified.

I tried the solutions provided in the following links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/e5337b0c-7f70-4603-859e-fbc7d0cf1c37

[SSIS Script Editor throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433791/ssis-script-editor-throws-an-exception)

Answer (score 12):

First of all go to Program and Features and check whether you have 
"Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications x86 Runtime 3.0" 
installed. Most probably you will see this below 
"Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications x64 Runtime 3.0"

If it is not installed then you have the same issue that i have.
To resolved this error, I put in my SQL Server installation disk. Then go to redist->VSTA->runtime->x86 and then run VSTA_RT30.msi

Comment: I tried it, and in installed programs both versions are available. However, I am still getting the same error message. BTW, I first installed the MS BI Suite. The both tools x64 and x86 were not available. Then I reinstalled Data Tools and Integrating Services. After that the both tools were available. But I am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround mention in this link solved my issue: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/776248/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-tools-applications-core

> Both the x86 and x64 runtimes must be installed, currently one or both the runtimes may be missing depending on the order of the SQL Server 2012 installation. As a workaround, check in Control Panel - Programs and determine which of the component is missing (it should be listed as Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications x86 or x64 Runtime 3.0). You can install the component manually from your installation disk or download from the \redist\VSTA\runtime\ folder.

Answer (score 1):

It is year 2021, when searching for the error, this is the top hit. The solution that worked for me with Visual Studio 2019 is to download and install "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2019"

Link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58317&WT.mc_id=DX_MVP4025064

Interestingly, this is not provided as an option in Visual Studio installer. The above needs to be manually downloaded and installed.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure this is the setup you are installing, there is other one "vsta_sdk.exe" did not work, the right one is "vsta_setup.exe".

Answer (score 0):

By now, SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 is out. Try updating your release and after that, you might even consider putting the Cumulative Update 1 on top of it.

More about CU1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2012/11/21/cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2012-service-pack-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

goto SQL server installer folder and install these msi files

redist/VSTA/designtime/VSTA_DT30msi
redist/VSTA/runtime/x64/VSTA_RT30.msi
redist/VSTA/runtime/x86/VSTA_RT30.msi