# Script Component in SSIS shows up as an empty 'VstaProjects' solution

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, script-component

I have SQL Server 2012 Client Tools installed on my Windows 8 machine. I am currently writing an SSIS project which has a lot of Script Tasks. When I double click on a Script Task and then click on the *Edit Script...* button, I observe the following:

- Expected Result: The Script Task Project loads in Visual Studio 2010 shell
- Actual Result: Empty Solution 'VstaProjects' opens up in Visual Studio 2010 shell

I was getting the expected results till the last day. I do not know what triggered this problem. I re-installed the SQL Server 2012 Client Tools and it did solve the problem but only temporarily, the issue appears again and it is very frustrating to work now.

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/c2fa4ac0-0852-4018-817e-d30933ce8b4d) talks about the same problem as mine but I do not see a solution there that works reliably.

Can someone out there help me solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot show Visual Studio Tools for Application editor in SSIS 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706780/cannot-show-visual-studio-tools-for-application-editor-in-ssis-2012)