# Cannot show Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Applications editor - MSBuildToolsPath

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

<sup>**Note:** There is a similar question [[cannot show Visual Studio Tools for Application editor in SSIS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706780/cannot-show-visual-studio-tools-for-application-editor-in-ssis-2012)], but the error and VS version are different.</sup>

When I attempt to view any SSIS package script in Visual Studio 2008, by clicking the <kbd>Edit Script...</kbd> button, I get this error:

> **Cannot show Visual Studio Tools for Applications editor. (Microsoft
>   Visual Studio)**
>   Unable to read the project file
>   'fileName.vbproj'. MSBuildToolsPath is not
>   specified for the ToolsVersion "14.0" defined at
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0", or
>   the value specified evaluates to the empty string.

I researched and found that MSBuild Tools Version 14.0 is for Visual Studio 2015<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion)</sup>.  I have VS2008, VS2013 and VS2017 installed, but this SSIS package was created and opened in VS2008, which uses `ToolsVersion` 4.0.

---

**What I've tried:**

- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled VS2008
- Took a look at the registry key listed in the error message.   I am not sure what to look for here.
  [image: Registry Editor Keys]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 breaks after the .NET Framework 4 is uninstalled
. If Visual Studio 2008 is installed, then Visual Studio 2010 is installed, and then the .NET Framework 4 is uninstalled (or both Visual Studio 2010 and the .NET Framework 4 are uninstalled), when you try to load a project on Visual Studio 2008, you get this error:

> “Unable to read the project file ‘Project.proj’. MSBuildToolsPath is not specified for the ToolsVersion “4.0” defined at “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0”, or the value specified evaluates to the empty string.”

This problem might occur because the Windows SDK v7.0A, or some of the registry keys that it uses, are still present on the computer.

To resolve this issue:

Make sure that Visual Studio 2010 is completely uninstalled (in “Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features”, make sure Visual Studio 2010 is not listed).
Make sure the following registry keys do not exist on the computer:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\14.0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersion\14.0
```

If you are working on a 64-bit operating system, delete these keys from the 32-bit part of the registry. To do this, click “Start -> Run”, type %WinDir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe, and then make the registry changes.

Visual Studio 2008 should now be fully functional.

Comment: This worked.  I wanted to add that I did not have VS2010 installed, but I did have VS2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework.  I removed this and deleted the registry keys.

Comment: Glad to help @KyleWilliamson

Comment: I had VS 2008, 2012 installed. After installation VS 2017 Enterprise this error appeared. There was only one key in my registry: `KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersion\14.0`. I removed it and the error has gone. (Also [here is the same receipt with pictures](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/16202-msbuildtoolspath-is-not-specified-for-the-toolsversion))